# What is the easy way to setOnClickListener() on all Activity Buttons

Tags: java, android

I want to know the simple way to add onclicklistener on all button. button can more then 20-30.
for eg..

> Button1 Id = "Submit"; Button2 Id = "Cancel" so on...

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

b1.setOnClickListener(this);
b2.setOnClickListener(this);
b3.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: There is a answer 
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.myrootlayout);
View v;
for(int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
    v = group.getChildAt(i);
    if(v instanceof Button) v.setOnClickListener(this)
}

but what is myrootlayout here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
for(int i=0; i < ((ViewGroup)getView()).getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = ((ViewGroup)getView()).getChildAt(i);
            if(v instanceof Button) {
                v.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `android:onClick="mainMenuButtonClick"` to your all buttons in **XML** and add `mainMenuButtonClick()` your activity and used `switch case` to identify **Button** like:

```
 public void mainMenuButtonClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.Button1:

            break;

        case R.id.Button2:
            break;
        case R.id.crmButton:
            break;
        case R.id.Button3:
            break;

        case R.id.Button4:

            break;

        case R.id.Button5:

            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: What if there's 100 buttons, I can switch case 100 times.. there must be some easy way.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a button array:

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[number_of_buttons];
```

Taking into account your ids, you could do the following:

```
for(int i=0; i<buttons.length; i++)
{
    buttons[i]=(Button)findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("button"+i,
"id", getPackageName());

    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Button can be any number 50, 100 anynumber and Ids are in different styles name

Comment: @MD ok, but it looks like, no one has answer for this common question.

Comment: The buttons are children of the same layout? This layout is inside of an XML file or is dynamically created? Which id has this layout?

Comment: Same layout, and how to assign id to layout ?

Comment: Use android:id="@+id/your_id" (in case that you use an XML layout)

Comment: this is the answer

ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.myrootlayout); View v; for(int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) { v = group.getChildAt(i); if(v instanceof Button) v.setOnClickListener(this) }

Answer (score 0):

Just use [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library like this:

```
@OnClick({ R.id.btndoor1, R.id.btndoor2, R.id.btndoor3 })
public void pickDoor(Button door) {
  if (door.hasPrizeBehind()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You win!", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Try again", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Where you have to inject the `onClick()` into the buttons like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_example, container, false);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);
```

Comment: Although this is applicable only for a *reasonable number* of Buttons. If you have 50, you should put them in a container like `LinearLayout`, then set a common `onClickListener` to all of its `Button` children in a loop...